# insert Array of object into Last index using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var a=[{"id":1, "name":"aaa", "age":31}, {"id":2, "name":"bbb", "age":23}, {"id":3, "name":"ccc", "age":24}]

var b=[{"id":4, "name":"ddd", "age":43}]

var result=[{"id":1, "name":"aaa", "age":31}, {"id":2, "name":"bbb", "age":23}, {"id":3, "name":"ccc", "age":24}, {"id":4, "name":"ddd", "age":43}]
```

I want to insert b into an index of 3. anybody know this one?

Comment: You should check this:- http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = a;
result.push(b[0]);
```

Comment: good call, though it only works when there is only 1 item in b

Comment: Yeah you can use apply() or call() method but OP hasn't mentioned that so I just answered that...

Answer (score 1):

`a.push.apply(a, b)`

This will call the Array's push method with as many arguments as there are items on b, that is to say `a.push(b[0], b[1], b[2], ...)`

Plain JS, no jQuery needed :)

PS: Note this modifies `a`.
If you don't want this, then you can first clone it with `Array.slice` :

```
var result = a.slice(); 
result.push.apply(this, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is

a[a.length] = b;

Here a.length is 3 that means next(or last) index to insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
var result = a.concat(b);
```

Comment: this won't produce the result the PR expects, he'll have an array as the last item in a instead (b being an array)

Comment: @Greg Concat function will concat two arrays and create a new array

Comment: Actually you're right @sameer, if the goal is not to modify `a` this is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the below code.

```
var a=[{"id": 1, "name":"aaa","age":31},{"id": 2, "name":"bbb","age":23},{"id": 3,name:"ccc","age":24}]
var b=[{"id": 4, "name":"ddd","age":43}];
function insertInto(index, a, b){
    var x = a.splice(index);
    a = a.concat(b);
    a = a.concat(x);
    retrun a;
}
a = insertInto(2,a,b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
var a = [{ "id": 1, "name": "aaa", "age": 31 }, { "id": 2, "name": "bbb", "age": 23 }, { "id": 3, "name": "ccc", "age": 24}];
        var b = [{ "id": 4, name: "ddd", "age": 43}];
        var result = a.concat(b);
```